# What determines the DateTime.Kind when ASP.Net receives a posted model with a DateTime property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, momentjs

We have a number of Vue pages, with Typescript models, that submit to the same controller action. The controller takes a single complex parameter, and the class features a DateTime property.

The Vue pages have been modified over time and now look quite unlike each other. However, in all cases the DateTime property is taken from an inputDateOfBirth field and mapped with Moment. The code tends to look a bit like this:

```
var dob = Helpers.ToMoment(this.inputDateOfBirth);

if (dob.isValid()) {
    this.dateOfBirth = dob.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Both `dateOfBirth` and `inputDateOfBirth` are listed as type `string` in the Typescript model.

In most cases, the complex parameter that ends up being received by the controller action has this DateTime property as `DateTime.Kind` of `Utc`. One of them, however, has a `DateTime.Kind` of `Unspecified`. This causes issues further down the line.

What determined the DateTime.Kind value of data interpreted by a C# controller action in ASP.NET MVC, and what can I do to ensure it's received consistently as Utc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format of the date can causes this difference.
Default model binder for DateTime expects [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) `Time zone designators`, which means that if your date string looks like this `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000Z`, then `DateTime.Kind` will be `UTC` as “Z” presented.
Or if like this `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000000-07:00`, where timezone offset “-07:00” is presented, `DateTime.Kind` will be `Local`.
If none of this attributes is presented, `DateTime.Kind` will be `Unspecified`.

Comment: In both cases at the point of submission, the date string is "1974-07-22 00:00:00" - yet one is being received as UTC and the other as unspecified. Are there any other factors at play?

Comment: @BobTway how did you check that sent data is actually in "1974-07-22 00:00:00 format? Inspecting JS object or request payload?

Comment: Added a breakpoint in Chrome and used a watch to check the status of the object right before the post action

Comment: @BobTway that can be an unreliable way to check what actually has been sent to the server. Can you check in Network panel the request and confirm format?
As I can see, ASP.NET uses simple [DateTime.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) inside, utilizing current threads culture info. Check Remarks section.

Comment: Both have 1974-07-22 00:00:00 as the value under request payload in the network tab

Comment: @BobTway that's very strange! In any case, to be sure that `Kind` is always UTC you will need to control what clients do send to API and make all data of date and time type conform to `ISO 8601` time format. So that means that everything Momento sends should have `Z` suffix or timezone offset. There is no way to control that behaviour on the server side in a way you would not need to write a custom model binder for each model you have.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. To save your sanity, I think I've traced this to an obscure bit of middleware in our stack that's being invoked prior to the controller action in some instances. So you're quite right about the way the date formats work!

Comment: @BobTway it's sad that we didn't figure out the reason. I looked in source codes of model binder for DateTime and inside DateTime.Parse itself. They are configured by format of input string and thread'ss CultureInfo which I assume should be the same for one request. The only place left to affect deserialization is custom binders, you can search in code for anything that inherits from `IModelBinder` or `IModelBinderProvider` — these two things are for custom binding configuration. But it's more likely that client side does something specific, but it's difficult to analyze it from my side, alas!